# How can I overlay floatingActionButton on WebviewScaffold

Tags: webview, dart, flutter

I try to Overlay a floatingActionButton on a Webview which is opened in a Widget.

```
"/widget": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
          clearCache: true,
          clearCookies: true,
          withJavascript: false,
          url: selectedUrl,
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Widget webview"),                
          ),              
          withLocalStorage: true,
          /*floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton (
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => new AddLinkPage()));
            },
            child: new Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),*/
        )
```

This doesn't work.

It is possible with `persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[]`, but then the view will be cut off

I use the flutter_webview_plugin: 0.1.5

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible.

The WebView is an Android view shown as overlay and is therefore always the top-most content that is shown.

Comment: I guess only waiting for https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter to become usable (don't know it's current state - haven't tried it myself)